# Calculating Joint Probability Distribution from Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Apologies in advance if this is considered an easy topic. I am absolutely mired and feel so defeated.

I am working with the following Bayesian Network:
[image]

I am being asked to compute the following:
`P(H, ~B, L, ~F, ~C)`
and
`P(F|L)`

I do not know much of where to start. I have reviewed the following resources:

- https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall16/cos402/lectures/402-lec13_.pdf
- http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~vittorio/Lecture12.pdf

My attempts are below:

***Calculating `P(F|L)`***

I know that this is considered a Top Down approach, and thus need to perform the following:

1. Rewrite the goal conditional probability of query variable Q in terms of Q and all of its parents (that are not evidence) given the evidence
2. Re-express each joint probability back to the probability of Q given all of its parents
3. Lookup values in the Bayesian Network

Therefore:

`P(F|L) =`

`= P(F,L)/P(L)`

`= P(F,L,B)/P(L)+P(F,L,~B)/P(L) (Total Probability)`

`= P(F,B|L) + P(F, ~B|L)`

`= P(F|B,L)P(B|L) + P(F|~B, L)P(~B|L) (Condtionalized Chain Rule)`

`= P(F|B,L)P(B) + P(F|~B, L)P(~B) (Independence)`

But I cannot see how that relates back to the graph. I also have no clue where to start for `P(H, ~B, L, ~F, ~C)`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H$ has no parents.  $H$ is the parent of $B$.  $H$ is the parent of $L$. $B$ and $L$ are the parents of $F$.  $L$ is the parent of $C$.

$\def\P{\operatorname{\sf P}}$Thus the factorisation for $\P(H,\neg B, L, \neg F, \neg C)$ is $$\begin{align}\P(H,\neg B, L, \neg F, \neg C)~&=~\mathsf P(H)\P(\neg B\mid H)\P(L\mid H)\P(\neg F\mid \neg B, L)\P(\neg C\mid L)\end{align}$$

---

Likewise the factorisation for $\P(F\mid L)$ is (by total probability)

$$\begin{align}\P(F\mid L)&=\P(F,B\mid L)+\P(F,\neg B\mid L)\\&=\P(F\mid B,L)\P(B\mid L)+\P(F\mid \neg B, L)\P(\neg B\mid L)\end{align}$$

Which you have correct until here.  However, $B$ and $L$ are *not* independent. They are *conditionally* independent given $H$.

$\begin{align}\P(B\mid L)&= \dfrac{\P(B\mid H)\P(L\mid H)\P(H)+\P(B\mid\neg H)\P(L\mid\neg H)\P(\neg H)}{\P(L\mid H)\P(H)+\P(L\mid\neg H)\P(\neg H)}\end{align}$

and likewise

$\begin{align}\P(\neg B\mid L)&= \dfrac{\P(\neg B\mid H)\P(L\mid H)\P(H)+\P(\neg B\mid\neg H)\P(L\mid\neg H)\P(\neg H)}{\P(L\mid H)\P(H)+\P(L\mid\neg H)\P(\neg H)}\end{align}$

Comment: Isn't `P(F,L)` different than `P(F|L)`? Additionally -- I have a lurking suspicion I am unable to truly compute these probabilities with the network given, and that I can only factor it down to a certain point, as you have done, and that I will not end up with a true value. Is that suspicion correct? (I believe the professor has provided an incorrect graphic).

Comment: Yes, they are different.  By definition of conditional probability, and the DAG factorisation. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(F\mid L)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(F,L)}{\mathsf P(L)}\\&=\dfrac{\sum_B\mathsf P(F,B,L)}{\mathsf P(L)}\\&=\dfrac{\sum_B \mathsf P(F\mid B,L)~\mathsf P(B\mid L)\mathsf P(L)}{\mathsf P(L)}\\&=\sum_B \mathsf P(F\mid B,L)~\mathsf P(B\mid L)\end{align}$$

Comment: The graph is correct, but on it, $H$ is $h_1$ and $\neg H$ is $h_2$, and so forth.  Everything you need is there. (Remember complementation $P(b_2\mid h_1)=1-P(b_1\mid h_1)$)